# Elasticsearch NEST C# Client - Bulk Partial update of a Nested List (time series data) by condition

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an index structure which has some normal properties and nested list properties. I need to update (partially)bulk/many documents Nested time series list based on a condition using **Elasticsearch .NET high level client NEST**.

**Example data**

List of history with dates and values is a nested object. I need to update only values matching with certain dates. **e.g. I only want to update some documents with some history dates. e.g. historydate 2020-02-01 value not other historydates values in history**. I know we can achieve full bulk document indexing and full nested list replacing but I don't know partial nested list.
I couldn't find NEST documentation anywhere. Could someone please help me.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "description": "market 1",
    "salesprice": 10.9,
    "cost": 7.95957,
    "history": [
      {
        "historydate": "2020-01-01",
        "quantity": 1
      },
      {
        "historydate": "2020-02-01",
        "quantity": 2
      },
      {
        "historydate": "2020-04-01",
        "quantity": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "description": "market 2",
    "salesprice": 12,
    "cost": 12,
    "history": [
      {
        "historydate": "2020-01-01",
        "quantity": 1
      },
      {
        "historydate": "2020-02-01",
        "quantity": 2
      },
      {
        "historydate": "2020-03-01",
        "quantity": 6
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "description": "market3",
    "salesprice": 15,
    "cost": 15,
    "history": [
      {
        "historydate": "2020-01-01",
        "quantity": 10
      },
      {
        "historydate": "2020-02-01",
        "quantity": 20
      },
      {
        "historydate": "2020-03-01",
        "quantity": 30
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The data I need to upadate is some documents (I have the data from different source with ids)
example 2 documents with 2 dates and different values

**example 1st document history values to be updated**

```
      {
        "historydate": "2020-02-01",
        "quantity": 9
      },
      {
        "historydate": "2020-03-01",
        "quantity": 11
      }
```

**example 2nd document history values to be updated**

```
      {
        "historydate": "2020-02-01",
        "quantity": 20
      },
      {
        "historydate": "2020-03-01",
        "quantity": 15
      }
```

I really appreciate your help.

Thank you,
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Use script, it will have to parse everymatching documents, but it will work.
note: day is a keyword on my side, if this is a date (maybe add class + mappings) , you will have to read a little of painless documentation.

```
var result = Client.UpdateByQuery<yourClass>(u => u
                                        .Index(index)
                                        .Query(r => r.Term(tt => //your query)
                                        .Script(ss
                                            => ss.Source("for (item in ctx._source.history) {if (item.historyDate == params.day) { item.quantity = params.qty;} }")
                                                    .Params(new Dictionary<string, object>()
                                                        {
                                                            {"day", day},
                                                            {"qty", newQty }
                                                        }).Lang("painless"))

                                        .Conflicts(Net.Conflicts.Proceed)
                                        .Refresh(true) //optional
                      );
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you very much for replying and for example code. I think I wasn't clear on onething in my question.  I have updated with additional information.
But main challenge is - I need to update specific documents (I have documents with ids) and each document has different values for the history dates to be updated.
How can we differentiate documents, dates and values in Params. 
Thank you.